# How to read Double from AnyObject in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3

I had it working on previous Swift versions like this:

```
let dictionary = responseObject as! NSDictionary
let result = dictionary.objectForKey("result")!
let geometry = result.objectForKey("geometry")!
let location = geometry.objectForKey("location")!            
let lat: Double = location.objectForKey("lat")!.doubleValue
```

As I understand, there is no `doubleValue` anymore, so I replaced it like this:

```
let dictionary = responseObject as! NSDictionary
let result: AnyObject = dictionary.object(forKey: "result") as AnyObject!
let geometry: AnyObject = result.object(forKey: "geometry") as AnyObject!
let location: AnyObject = geometry.object(forKey: "location") as AnyObject!
let lat: Double = location.double(forKey: "lat")
```

And it crashes:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary doubleForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1584aba10
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary doubleForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1584aba10'
```

Comment: `let dictionary = responseObject as? [String: Any] ?? [:]`

Comment: `let result = dictionary["result"] as? [String: Any] ?? [:]`and so on

Comment: @LeoDabus Works good. Make it an answer, I will accept it. Made last line `let lat: Double = location["lat"] as! Double`

Comment: same as result or others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to cast it from `Any` to `[String: Any]` or to another type you need to get from it:

```
let dictionary = responseObject as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
let result = dictionary["result"] as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
let location = result["location"] as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
let lat = location["lat"] as? Double ?? 0
```